# Git will not Sync Changes in VSCode: error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git

[image]

Sync Changes gets this error

I tried doing a Pull as it suggests by using the Source Control menu.  I tried both the Pull and the Pull/Push sync and just keep getting the same.

Also tried:
[image]

Comment: Resolved: https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/52z0j6phhnjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check https://www.githubstatus.com, because there is some disruption in Github.